# Exception handling in Multicast Delegate

Tags: c#

I have a multicast delegate thru which I am invoking two methods. If there is an exception in the first method and its handled, how to continue with the second method invocation? I am attaching the code below. In the below code, the first method throws an exception. But I would like to know how to continue with executing the second method thru multicast delegate invocation.

```
public delegate void TheMulticastDelegate(int x,int y);
    class Program
    {
            private static void MultiCastDelMethod(int x, int y)
            {
                    try
                    {
                            int zero = 0;
                            int z = (x / y) / zero; 
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {                               
                            throw ex;
                    }
            }

            private static void MultiCastDelMethod2(int x, int y)
            {
                    try
                    {
                            int z = x / y;
                            Console.WriteLine(z);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                            throw ex;
                    }
            }
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                    TheMulticastDelegate multiCastDelegate = new TheMulticastDelegate(MultiCastDelMethod);
                    TheMulticastDelegate multiCastDelegate2 = new TheMulticastDelegate(MultiCastDelMethod2);

                    try
                    {
                            TheMulticastDelegate addition = multiCastDelegate + multiCastDelegate2;

                            foreach (TheMulticastDelegate multiCastDel in addition.GetInvocationList())
                            {
                                    multiCastDel(20, 30);
                            }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }

                    Console.ReadLine();
            }
    }
```

Comment: why not put an error handling inside your loop? then continue the loop if an exception occcurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move try..catch inside the loop:

```
foreach (TheMulticastDelegate multiCastDel in addition.GetInvocationList())
{
    try
    {
        multiCastDel(20, 30);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Besides you'd replace `throw ex;` with `throw ;` as the former creates a new exception, which is unnecessary. It should look like:

```
private static void MultiCastDelMethod(int x, int y)
{
    try
    {
        int zero = 0;
        int z = (x / y) / zero;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no need to add any try catch. As You are not handling anything and just throwing exception.